# jquery airport plugin : How can I make it work with special characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, special-characters

I'm using the cool [jquery airport plugin](http://www.unwrongest.com/projects/airport/) and trying to make it accept special characters (like accents, "&", etc.). By default it only works with a-z.

Has anybody found how to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a `chars` array that you can add characters to.

```
var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', ' ', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '-'];
```

Doing this should be enough.

PS: Sometimes, looking at the source code of a program can be really enlightening. ;-)

Comment: Yep, I did that soon enough, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up the chars array correctly.

```
var chars = ['a', ..., 'z', ' ', '-', '&', 'ä', 'ö', 'ü'];
```

Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F6Sq4/

The examples uses some german umlauts (äöü), but you might include any other char.