# Special Characters (UTF-8) with jQuery, Airport library

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, utf-8

I've been trying to use the airport library and my problem is that it won't print special characters like ä, ö, &, etc. 
I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389057/jquery-airport-plugin-how-can-i-make-it-work-with-special-characters) but that doesn't solve my problem either.

I've included the library like this:

```
<script language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="path/jquery.airport-1.1.js"></script>
```

Can anyone help me? I'm using codeigniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the exact suggestion in the post you linked to works flawless.

Check this [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/F6Sq4/)

Note that you have to modify the plugin code directly and add the characters you want to the chars array inside the plugins code. That's exactly what I did. I added ä,ö,ü add the end and it works

Comment: you are absolutely right, thanks. it was a problem with my codeigniter settings, i just had to set it up properly.